# How to create session with SQL Server in fluent hibernate

Tags: sql-server, fluent-nhibernate, isession

I'm getting exception while creating connection with SQL Server.

`ISession` factory is shown below from which I'm getting exception:

```
private static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
{
   return Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(FluentNHibernate.Cfg.Db.MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008
            .ConnectionString(c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("FNHConnection"))
            )
            .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<SessionProvider>())
            .BuildSessionFactory();

    //// code added to configure the database connection .. 
    //var FNHConfig = MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.ConnectionString(c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("FNHConnection"));
    //PersistenceModel persistenceModel = new PersistenceModel();
    //persistenceModel.AddMappingsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly());
    //_config.AddProperties(FNHConfig.ToProperties());
    //persistenceModel.Configure(_config);
    ////return _config.BuildSessionFactory();

    //return Config.BuildSessionFactory();
}
```

The following exception is thrown:

> Locating source for 'd:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Cfg\Configuration.cs'.
>   (No checksum.)
>   The file 'd:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Cfg\Configuration.cs'
>   does not exist.
>   Looking in script documents for 'd:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Cfg\Configuration.cs'...
>   Looking in the projects for 'd:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Cfg\Configuration.cs'.
>   The file was not found in a project.
>   Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\VC\crt\src\'...
>   Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\VC\atlmfc\src\mfc\'...
>   Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\VC\atlmfc\src\atl\'...
>   Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\VC\atlmfc\include\'...
>   The debug source files settings for the active solution indicate that
>   the debugger will not ask the user to find the file:
>   d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Cfg\Configuration.cs.
>   The debugger could not locate the source file
>   'd:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Cfg\Configuration.cs'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing BuildConfiguration()

```
 .Mappings(m =>
            m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<SessionProvider>())
 .BuildConfiguration()
 .BuildSessionFactory();
```